# How to move Recycleview item to Fragment of navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, cardview

I want to start intent from ViewHolder class to the Fragment of Navigation Drawer Fragment class. Please see the code below.

```
public class LinearViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

public TextView countryName;
public ImageView countryPhoto;
public Context context;


public LinearViewHolder(View v) {
    super(v);
    context = itemView.getContext();
    countryName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
    countryPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_photo);
    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int pos = getAdapterPosition();
            if (pos == 0) {
                //here we go to ActivityFragment class???

            } else if (pos == 1) {

                //here we go to ActivityFragment class???

            } else if (pos == 2) {
                //here we go to ActivityFragment class???

            } else if (pos == 3) {


            } else if (pos == 4) {

            } else if (pos == 5) {

            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

And the FragmentActivity.class code is this below!

```
public class ActivityFragment extends Fragment {

private List<ActivitySetData> history;
RecyclerView recList;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.actvity_toolbar, container, false);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) v.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_two);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
            (CollapsingToolbarLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.appbar);
    appBarLayout.setExpanded(true);

    // hiding & showing the title when toolbar expanded & collapsed
    appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        boolean isShow = false;
        int scrollRange = -1;

        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            if (scrollRange == -1) {
                scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
            }
            if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                collapsingToolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
                isShow = true;
            } else if (isShow) {
                collapsingToolbar.setTitle(" ");
                isShow = false;
            }
        }
    });

    try {
        Glide.with(this).load(R.color.light_blue).into((ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.backdrop));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    recList = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recList.setLayoutManager(llm);

    initializeData();
    initializeAdapter();


    return v;
}

private void initializeData() {
    history = new ArrayList<>();
    history.add(new ActivitySetData(R.color.light_blue, "Getting knowing the Activity", getString(R.string.activity_first)));
    history.add(new ActivitySetData(R.color.light_blues1, "Navigation Through Activities", getString(R.string.activity_second)));
    history.add(new ActivitySetData(R.color.light_blues2, "Tasks", getString(R.string.activity_third)));
    history.add(new ActivitySetData(R.color.light_blues3, "The Talkback Stack", getString(R.string.activity_four)));
    history.add(new ActivitySetData(R.color.light_blues4, "Activity Life Cycle", getString(R.string.activity_five)));
    history.add(new ActivitySetData(R.color.light_blues6, "Activity Life Cycle Methods", getString(R.string.activity_six)));

}

private void initializeAdapter() {
    ActivityAdapter adapter = new ActivityAdapter(history);
    recList.setAdapter(adapter);
}


private void setSupportActionBar(Toolbar toolbar) {
}

}
```

And the code of my Parent MainActivity.class is below

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

//Defining Variables
private NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
String showFragmentCheck;
private TextView tool;
FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
LinearLayout linearLayoutSelectLocation;
private TextView textViewCancel;
private TextView textViewLike;
private TextView textViewShare;
private ImageView ic_short;
private FloatingActionButton fab;

private static final String SHOWCASE_ID = "sequence example";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    register_view();
    presentShowcaseSequence(); // one second delay


    textViewLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.mytutoandroid"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    });

    textViewShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.mytutoandroid");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {



        }
    });

    textViewCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            linearLayoutSelectLocation.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
    ic_short.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UiShortcuts.class);
            // intent.putExtra("lastFragment","News");
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }
    });
    mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    showFragmentCheck = getIntent().getStringExtra("checkFragment");
    if (showFragmentCheck == null) {
        showChildFragment("Getting Started");
    } else {
        showChildFragment(showFragmentCheck);
    }

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            showChildFragment(menuItem.getTitle().toString());
            return false;
        }
    });
    /**
     * Setup Drawer Toggle of the Toolbar
     */
    android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.app_name,
            R.string.app_name);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

public void register_view() {

    tool = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    tool.setOnClickListener(this);
    textViewLike = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLike);
    textViewShare = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewShare);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    textViewCancel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCancel);
    linearLayoutSelectLocation = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutSelectLocation);
    ic_short = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.choose_short);
    ic_short.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void showChildFragment(String fragmentTitle) {
    if (fragmentTitle.equals("Activity")) {                        // on 2nd item in the menu, do somethin
        tool.setText("Intro to Activity");
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, new ActivityFragment()).commit();
    } else if (fragmentTitle.equals("Getting Started")) {                        // on 2nd item in the menu, do somethin
        tool.setText("Android Development");
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, new MainFragment()).commit();
    } else if (fragmentTitle.equals("Services")) {                        // on 2nd item in the menu, do somethin
        tool.setText("Intro to Services");
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, new ServicesFragment()).commit();
    } else if (fragmentTitle.equals("Content Provider")) {                        // on 2nd item in the menu, do somethin
        tool.setText("Intro to Content Provider");
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, new ContentFragment()).commit();
    } else if (fragmentTitle.equals("BroadCast Receiver")) {                        // on 2nd item in the menu, do somethin
        tool.setText("Intro to BroadCast Receiver");
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, new BroadCastFragment()).commit();
    } else if (fragmentTitle.equals("Networking")) {                        // on 2nd item in the menu, do somethin
        tool.setText("Intro to Networking");
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, new NetworkingFragment()).commit();
    } else if (fragmentTitle.equals("Android Manifest")) {                        // on 2nd item in the menu, do somethin
        tool.setText("Intro to Manifests");
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, new ManiFragment()).commit();
    } else if (fragmentTitle.equals("References")) {                        // on 2nd item in the menu, do somethin
        tool.setText("References");
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, new References()).commit();
    } else {
        showChildFragment("Getting Started");
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.choose_short || v.getId() == R.id.toolbar_title) {

        presentShowcaseSequence();

    }
}

private void presentShowcaseSequence() {

    ShowcaseConfig config = new ShowcaseConfig();
    config.setDelay(500); // half second between each showcase view

    MaterialShowcaseSequence sequence = new MaterialShowcaseSequence(this, SHOWCASE_ID);

    sequence.setOnItemShownListener(new MaterialShowcaseSequence.OnSequenceItemShownListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(MaterialShowcaseView itemView, int position) {
            Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "Item #" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    sequence.setConfig(config);

    sequence.addSequenceItem(ic_short, "Shortcut for Android topics\nFind the Android Content with details.", "GOT IT");


    sequence.start();

}

}
```

Comment: Go to its parent activity not fragment and manage it from there

Comment: Is it not possible in this case?

Comment: yes it is possible, manage with different intent values

Comment: Would you please provide me some code to guide me here?

Comment: can you post your parent activity so that i can get better idea

Comment: Now you can see this parent class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Adapter**

```
 v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int pos = getAdapterPosition();
        if (pos == 0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("checkFragment", "ActivityFragment");
            context.startActivity(intent);

        } else if (pos == 1) {

            //same as above

        } else if (pos == 2) {
            ///same as above

        } else if (pos == 3) {


        } else if (pos == 4) {

        } else if (pos == 5) {

        }
    }
});
```

**In MainActivity**

```
 mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    showFragmentCheck = getIntent().getStringExtra("checkFragment");

    if (showFragmentCheck == null) {
        showChildFragment("Getting Started");
    } else {
         if (showFragmentCheck.equalsIgnoreCase("ActivityFragment")) {
                showChildFragment("Activity");
            }else
            {
               showChildFragment(showFragmentCheck);
            } 
    }
```

Comment: Yes it's work but it's move to MainAcvity.class instead of ActivityFragment.class please you will guide it to provide your MainActivity.class code

Comment: @Atif Umar Where ? I cant see any changes

Comment: @Atif Umar check it now, I also changed lil in adapter

Comment: @AtifUmar Great and welcome :) Glad I could help you

Answer (score 0):

try with this way  or try with this link [Click Here to more](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
         android:id="@+id/cardList"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
   />
```

Dependency:-

compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0-rc1'

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
  RecyclerView recList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cardList);
  recList.setHasFixedSize(true);
  LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
  llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
  recList.setLayoutManager(llm);
 }


 public class ContactInfo {
  protected String name;
  protected String surname;
  protected String email;
  protected static final String NAME_PREFIX = "Name_";
  protected static final String SURNAME_PREFIX = "Surname_";
  protected static final String EMAIL_PREFIX = "email_";
}




  public static class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
 protected TextView vName;
 protected TextView vSurname;
 protected TextView vEmail;
 protected TextView vTitle;

 public ContactViewHolder(View v) {
      super(v);
      vName =  (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
      vSurname = (TextView)  v.findViewById(R.id.txtSurname);
      vEmail = (TextView)  v.findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
      vTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
     }
    }

 public class ContactAdapter extends
          RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactAdapter.ContactViewHolder> {
 private List<ContactInfo> contactList;

  public ContactAdapter(List<ContactInfo> contactList) {
        this.contactList = contactList;
  }

 @Override
 public int getItemCount() {
      return contactList.size();
 }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder, int i) {
    ContactInfo ci = contactList.get(i);
    contactViewHolder.vName.setText(ci.name);
    contactViewHolder.vSurname.setText(ci.surname);
    contactViewHolder.vEmail.setText(ci.email);
    contactViewHolder.vTitle.setText(ci.name + " " + ci.surname);
  }

 @Override
 public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.card_layout, viewGroup, false);

    return new ContactViewHolder(itemView);
 }

 public static class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: No dear it's not understandable for this.

Comment: make it as fragment if you needed